# iPhone UIPickerView not animating on device

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got a very simple screen with a 2 component UIPickerView used to perform a conversion. All I'm doing is when one reel is changed I automatically move the other to an appropriate position, using animation.

So, I've got this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // adjust the other component accordingly
    [pickerView selectRow:row 
              inComponent:(component == kPickerComponent1) ? kPickerComponent2 : kPickerComponent1
                 animated:YES];
}
```

This works perfectly in the simulator, with a smooth animation as expected, however on the device it still works but without the animation.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think u have to get build from below minimum level of sdk.

change base sdk to 3.1

select in xcode select app below the target folder

then double click it

in build tab type "deploy"

ios deployment target to ios 3.1 or ur exact device version.

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I'm running Xcode 4.1 and only have 4.3 available as a base SDK (deploying to 3.1.3). I could install older SDKs, but not sure that's a route I want to take. Shouldn't it still work with the latest base SDK?